# Group Theory Exponent and Abelian Proof

Tags: group-theory, proof-writing

Let G be a group such that $x, y \in G$

Show that, if $(xy)^2=x^2y^2$ or $(xy)^{-1}=x^{-1}y^{-1}$, then xy=yx.

This can also be thought of as the exponent rule $(xy)^n$=$x^ny^n$ if xy=yx is true for $x, y, n \in G$ if and only if G is abelian.

I know I will have to prove this in both directions but I need some help manipulating the equations to be able to write a proof on it.

Comment: This is surely a duplicate...

Comment: Since you're sure this is a duplicate could you please help me find the original question? I searched around but maybe I wasn't searching for the correct thing. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure which of the statements you are trying to show. I assume the first since the second seems like a comment, so I shall give hints for the first.

Show that if $(xy)^2=x^2y^2$ OR $(xy)^{-1}=x^{-1}y^{-1}$, then $xy=yx$.

**HINT.** Because of the OR, you need to show if $(xy)^2=x^2y^2$, then $xy=yx$ and if $(xy)^{-1}=x^{-1}y^{-1}$, then $xy=yx$.

For the first, what is $(xy)^2$? (not the given equality)

> $(xy)^2=(xy)(xy)=xyxy$

So then what can we say?

> $xyxy=x^2y^2$ but then $x^{-1}xyxyy^{-1}=x^{-1}x^2y^2y^{-1}$ and this yields $yx=xy$.

Now the other part. Using what is sometimes called the 'Sock and Shoes Equality', what is $(xy)^{-1}$?

> $(xy)^{-1}=y^{-1}x^{-1}$

So then what can we say?

> $y^{-1}x^{-1}=x^{-1}y^{-1}$. The inverse of $xy$ is $(xy)^{-1}=y^{-1}x^{-1}=x^{-1}y^{-1}$. So $xy(xy)^{-1}=xyx^{-1}y^{-1}=e$. Then $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}yx=yx$ so that $xy=yx$.